# Homebrew issue with mac M1

Tags: homebrew, apple-m1

I tried to install homebrew in a new mac with M1 chip. When I do brew --version, I got this:

```
brew --version
Homebrew 3.1.2-40-g520b811
Homebrew/homebrew-core N/A
```

Anyone knows how to fix it Homebrew/homebrew-core?

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
cd /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps
mkdir homebrew
cd homebrew
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core /opt/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core --depth=1
```

```
brew --version
Homebrew 3.1.2-40-g520b811
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision bb47919; last commit 2021-04-19)
```

After that I could finally use brew to install packages.